Можно ли нейросеть обучать каждый раз на новых данных?
Например в pytorch можно применять различные методы аугментации данных (в том числе регулировать вероятность их применения). Так вот получается, что каждый раз одна и та же картинка будет изменяться перед выходом по-разному. Меня интересует вопрос. Помогает ли такой способ улучшать точность модели?
У меня есть несколько мыслей на этот счет

Данные после аугментации становятся сложнее. Но как я понимаю, эта проблема решается бОльшим временем обучения сети и усложнением ее архитектуры)
Модель больше не видит одинаковых картинок, а значит есть возможность обучиться на определенной картинке только один раз. С одной стороны хорошо, потому что разнообразия больше, с другой стороны обычно модель видит десятки-сотни раз одну и ту же картинку в процессе обучения. Может быть показывать картинку один раз недостаточно, чтобы модель действительно что-то успела выучить?


Конечно можно, если же это не повторяющаяся модель даже в Data Science  есть такая фишка которое обучает модель с помощь деревьев.
